# Explode textarea entry and have form send array

Tags: php, arrays, database, forms

I have a textarea which asks the user for the flow. The user can input multiples flows which are separated by commas. I want to be able to explode that entry into an array and have that array passed in the form instead of the entry variable($lot_entry). Not sure how to go about it. An attempt at the solution is as follows:

```
    print "<form name=\"entry1\" method=\"get\" ".
        "action=\"process_crawl_chart_plot.php\">\n";   
            print "<table border=\"1\" cellspacing=\"2\" cellpadding=\"8\">\n";         
    print "<tr>\n";
    print "<th bgcolor=\"#E9E9E9\"><font size=\"-1\">Enter Lot(s) Of The Same Flow\n Separated By Spaces</th>\n";
    print "<td colspan=\"2\">\n";
    print "<textarea cols=\"40\" rows=\"5\"  name=\"lot_entry\">$lot_entry</textarea>\n";
    print "</td>\n";
    print "</tr>\n";


    print "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"chosen_lot[]\" value=\"$chosen_lot\">\n";
    print "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"serial_flow\" value=\"$serial_flow\">\n";          
    print "<td align=\"center\" colspan=\"2\">\n";
   print "<button name=\"process_action\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Graph\"".
         "style=\"color: green\"><b>Select</b></button>\n";
    print "</tr>\n";
    print "</tr>\n";
    print "</form>";

if (!empty($_POST['lot_entry']))    {       
    $chosen_lot_entry_arr = explode(' ',$_POST['lot_entry']);
    foreach($chosen_lot_entry_arr as $lot_entry1){
    $query = "SELECT serial_ls FROM lot_start WHERE lot = '$lot_entry1'";
    if ($show_query == 1) { print "<font size=\"-2\">".$query."</font>\n"; }
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
   $temp_data = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    while ($temp_data = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {    
    $chosen_lot[] = $temp_data[0];  
    }       
}
```

}

Comment: Place your `if(!empty())...` code in `process_crawl_chart_plot.php`, and change it to `if (!empty($_POST['lot_entry'])) { $chosen_lot_entry_arr = explode(',',$_POST['lot_entry']);...`

Comment: @Sean Changed code according to your recommendation, still not working. Updated code to show what exactly I did.

Comment: Just realized that your form is `method=\"get\"`, not `method="post"`, so it should be with `$_GET` -> `if (!empty($_GET['lot_entry'])) { $chosen_lot_entry_arr = explode(',',$_GET['lot_entry']);...` instead of using `$_POST`. Also, is the code you posted on `process_crawl_chart_plot.php`?

Comment: @sean I tried method="get" as well but still isn't working, and yes the code is on process_crawl_chart_plot.php. When I submit the form my URL looks like the following: process_crawl_chart_plot.php?lot_entry=14-418&chosen_lot%5B%5D=&serial_flow1=&process_action=Graph so the chosen_lot and serial_flow1 are being passed but no values are being assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `explode(' ', $lot_entry)`. This will make each word a different element in the array.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I think I have correct format to explode the form entry into an array, however I am unsure how to pass the newly created array instead of the form entry entered by the user in the form. So, I'd like to pass $chosen_lot[] when submit is clicked, and not $lot_entry.